# imagem não aparece em javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
 var contexto = canvas.getContext("2d");
 contexto.fillStyle = "dimgray";
 contexto.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 contexto.fillStyle = "lightgray";
 contexto.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, 80);
 contexto.fillStyle = "lightgray";
 contexto.fillRect(0,380, canvas.width,100);
 contexto.fillStyle = "white";

for(var i = 0; i <25; i++)
{
    contexto.fillRect(i*30-5, 185, 20, 4);
    contexto.fillRect(i*30-5, 280, 20, 4);
}
var imagem = new image();
imagem.src = "http://a-dilminha.appspot.com/dilminha.png"

var x = 320;
var y = 400;

imagem.onload = function(){
//a imagem não aparece
contexto.drawImage(imagem, x, y, imagem.width, imagem.height)
}
```

a imagem não aparece ou carrega, eu tentei de tudo e não achei uma resposta.

[código completo](https://www.mediafire.com/file/gky66r6bw5oe6wa/jogo.zip/file)

Comment: não funcionou...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O construtor de imagens do JavaScript, na verdade, se chama `Image`. No seu código, você colocou `new image()` ao invés de `new Image()`, com o "I" maiúsculo.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Valeu!!! funcionou! só não dei upvote por que não posso...

Answer (score 0):

Além do erro citado pelo Gustavo Sampaio, o evento `onload` deve ser aplicado a `imagem` que é a imagem a ser carregada, e não ao `contexto` que se refere ao canvas. Basta trocar `contexto.onload` por `imagem.onload`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
var contexto = canvas.getContext("2d");
contexto.fillStyle = "dimgray";
contexto.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
contexto.fillStyle = "lightgray";
contexto.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, 80);
contexto.fillStyle = "lightgray";
contexto.fillRect(0,380, canvas.width, 100);
contexto.fillStyle = "white";

for(var i = 0; i <25; i++)
    {
        contexto.fillRect(i*30-5, 185, 20, 4);
        contexto.fillRect(i*30-5, 280, 20, 4);
    }
var imagem = new Image();
imagem.src = "http://a-dilminha.appspot.com/dilminha.png"

var x = 320;
var y = 0;

imagem.onload = function(){
   contexto.drawImage(imagem, x, y, imagem.width, imagem.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" style="border: solid 1px black; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></canvas>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!